# total / count items from list json response

Tags: java, rest-assured

im trying to get count / total number of records from list api using Restassured.

Please share thoughts on how can we get it.

ex:

```
{
    "final list": [
        {
            "id": 123,
            "name": "sachin"
        },
        {
            "id": 234,
            "name": "sourav"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am expecting total as 2 here. please suggest.

Comment: jsonObject.length , how about that ???

Comment: JsonObject mean responsespecification?

Comment: if its JSONArray you should use array.length(); or if JSONObject use object.length();

Comment: pls tell me in restassured code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got answer to my question.

here is the code for rest assured

expect().body("final_list.findall.size()",equalTo(2)).when().get("/list.json);

thanks

Comment: a slightly simpler solution is:

expect().body("final_list", hasSize(2)).when().get("/list.json);

Answer (score 5):

if you expect `final_list` to have 2 elements, you can use the `hasSize()` matcher:

```
expect().body("final_list", hasSize(2)).when().get("/list.json);
```

I found this in the list of matchers from the Matchers class Java doc:

http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#hasSize(org.hamcrest.Matcher)

Answer (score 3):

Yo can do the following:

```
jp = new JsonPath(response.asString());
String numFromsResponse = jp.get("final list.id.size()").toString();
```

Answer (score -1):

You  may use:

```
var json = {
    "final list": [
        {
            "id": 123,
            "name": "sachin"
        },
        {
            "id": 234,
            "name": "sourav"
        }
    ]
}
```

and then

```
json["final list"].length
```

Comment: hi anand.. im verifying response data using junit and i wanted to test number of records in the list json response